# Matrix equivalence relation related to similarity and rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

The problem statement, all variables and given/known data.

Let $X:=\{A ∈ \mathbb C^{n×n}:rank(A)=1\}$. Determine a representative for each equivalence class, for the equivalence relation "similarity" in $X$.

The attempt at a solution.

I am a pretty lost with this problem: I know that, thinking in terms of columns $X$ is the set of matrices with just one linearly independent column. In an $n×n$ matrix there are n columns, so I thought that maybe there could be n representatives of this equivalence relation, but I couldn't prove it and in fact I am not at all convinced this is true. I would appreciate suggestions to solve the problem.

Comment: How does two matrices being similar relate their eigenvalues? What does the rank being $1$ tells you about the possible eigenvalues? What is the canonical (jordan normal) form of representation of similarity? Note that necessarily the jordan normal form of a matrix is $X$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If rank$(A)=1$, then any nonzero column of $A$ is an *eigenvector* of $A$, and two such matrices will be similar iff they have the same eigenvalue for their selected eigenvector. 
(Note that eigenvalue $0$ is ruled out.)